# How do I turn off the Meow Bottom bar animation?

Tags: java, android

I need to disable transition animation for *Meow Bottom Bar* written in ***Java***, that is, for

```html
'com.etebarian: meow-bottom-navigation-java:1.2.0'
```

I tried toggling animation via * setAnimation () * unfortunately it didn't work.
I also searched the documentation for this library, but I did not find anything related to animation.
Can you please help me? My Bottom Bar code is below

Bottom Bar Code

```
    MeowBottomNavigation bottomNavigationBar = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_bar);

    bottomNavigationBar.add(new MeowBottomNavigation.Model(ID_HOME, R.drawable.svg_home));
    bottomNavigationBar.add(new MeowBottomNavigation.Model(ID_MESSAGE, R.drawable.svg_message));
    bottomNavigationBar.add(new MeowBottomNavigation.Model(ID_NOTIFICATIONS, R.drawable.svg_notifications));
    bottomNavigationBar.add(new MeowBottomNavigation.Model(ID_SETTINGS, R.drawable.svg_setting));

    } catch (Exception error) {
        Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
    }
    bottomNavigationBar.setOnClickMenuListener(new MeowBottomNavigation.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClickItem(MeowBottomNavigation.Model item) {
            try {
                switch (item.getId()) {
                    default:
                        Log.d(TAG, "switch default meow bottom bar");
                        break;
                    case ID_TASKS:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
                        finish();
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        break;
                    case ID_CLOCK:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageActivity.class));
                        finish();
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        break;
                    case ID_CALENDAR:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationsActivity.class));
                        finish();
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        break;
                    case ID_SETTINGS:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingActivity.class));
                        finish();
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        break;

                }
            } catch (Exception error) {
                Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    bottomNavigationBar.setOnShowListener(new MeowBottomNavigation.ShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShowItem(MeowBottomNavigation.Model item) {
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "bottomNavigationBar ShowListener");
            } catch (Exception error) {
                Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
            }
        }
    });

    bottomNavigationBar.setOnReselectListener(new MeowBottomNavigation.ReselectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReselectItem(MeowBottomNavigation.Model item) {
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "bottomNavigationBar ReselectListener");
            } catch (Exception error) {
                Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    bottomNavigationBar.show(ID_HOME);
```

I want to switch between activities this way

Bottom Bar XML

```
<com.etebarian.meowbottomnavigation.MeowBottomNavigation
    android:id="@id/bottom_navigation_bar"
    style="@style/MyBottomNavigation"/>
```

Bottom Bar Style

```
<style name="MyBottomNavigation">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="mbn_backgroundBottomColor">?android:windowBackground</item>
    <item name="mbn_circleColor">?colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="mbn_defaultIconColor">?colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="mbn_selectedIconColor">?colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="mbn_shadowColor">?colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set `has_animation` attribute to `false` to disable animation, add `<item name="mbn_hasAnimation">false</item>` to your bottom nav style

```
<style name="MyBottomNavigation">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="mbn_backgroundBottomColor">?android:windowBackground</item>
    <item name="mbn_circleColor">?colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="mbn_defaultIconColor">?colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="mbn_selectedIconColor">?colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="mbn_shadowColor">?colorAccent</item>
    <item name="mbn_hasAnimation">false</item>
</style>
```

As you can see inside class `MeowBottomNavigation`, you will find `duration` is set to `1L` if `hasAnimation` is `false`

```
line 273:: val animDuration = if (enableAnimation && hasAnimation) d else 1L
```

Comment: You did not understand me.I use 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation-java:1.2.0', instead of 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation:1.2.0'. 
And I have no such attribute '**<item name="mbn_hasAnimation">false</item>**'